# C# Debug Extension of Dictionary which contains keys and Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to add an extension for a Dictionary who takes key-value a key and a Dictionary, as follows, but I receive error 'Cannot implicitly convert type bool to string':

```
public static string GetParameterValue(
    this Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> src, string section, string key, out string value)
{
    value = null;
    if (src.TryGetValue(section, out Dictionary<string, string> sectionValue))
    {
        bool hasValue =  sectionValue.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return hasValue; //error... how to return value here when hasValue is true?
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I have multiple sections (imagine categories) and each section has a huge list of parameters and their values; section One has a list of key/value pairs, section Two the same etc.
I am trying to have a Dictionary which is of the form

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Sections = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

which I populate like

```
Sections["Italian"].Add("Good morning", "Buon giorno");
```

and I want to have an extension so that I can do

```
string myWord = Sections.GetParameterValue("Italian", "Good morning")
```

so that myWord is "Buon giorno".

Maybe could you help?

Comment: Your function specifies a return type of string, but the output of the method `TryGetValue()` is boolean

Comment: @CarloR Correct; how should I correct it, what is the correct statement?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Alexei you are right and additionally thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Sections = new Dictionary<string,  Dictionary<string, string> >();

Sections.AddParameterValue("Italian","Good afternoon", "Buon afternoon");
Sections.AddParameterValue("Italian","Good morning", "Buon giorno");
    
string myWord = Sections.GetParameterValue("Italian", "Good morning");


public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetParameterValue(
    this Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> src, string key1,  string key2)
    {
        if (src.TryGetValue(key1, out var sectionValue))
                if (sectionValue.TryGetValue(key2, out var result)) return result;
    
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static void AddParameterValue(
    this Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> src, string section, string key, string value)
    {
        if (!src.TryGetValue(section, out _)) src[section] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (src[section].TryGetValue(key, out _)) src[section][key] = value;
        else src[section].Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are brilliant! That's it, exactly. I was trying to manipulate the error so that it returns the string and not a bool value, but as it turns out the solution was a bit more complicated. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Nick - What do you mean by "manipulate the error so that it returns the string"?

Comment: @Enigmativity On the code that I have, instead of a value, the code returns true or false, like, if it's an "error" or not. I was needed the actual value, which Serge did so elegantly..